# Storing a variable in localstrorage correctly without resetting to 0

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, local-storage

I'm trying to store a int that I will be manipulating a lot in javascript, but I can't even store it correctly in the first place to keep it's value.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("localValue") === null || undefined ) {
    var preValue = 0;
    localStorage.setItem("localValue",preValue);
    var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localValue"));
    console.log("newly set variable!");
}
else
{
    var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localValue"));
    console.log("there was one here before!");
}
```

Every time I refresh the page, it's reset back to 0. But I want it to keep it's value from the previous "session" as in after refreshing the page.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("localValue") === null || undefined` doesn't do what you think it does. But in this case, I don't think it matters. Just change it to `localStorage.getItem("localValue") === null`

Comment: Aren't you manually setting it to 0 with these two lines? `var preValue = 0;
    localStorage.setItem("localValue",preValue);`

Comment: @J.Chen But he only does that if the value isn't found.

Comment: localStorage can only store string not int, so you have to convert it to string then reconvert it back to int.

Comment: @MrNew It automatically converts to string.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: i'm not sure if that was the mistake, but the function that increases this value is: function gainValue() {
 value = value + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
 JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem("localValue",value));
} is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: in the `else` part you don't need `var value` again as its already set above. Tried it on plnkr initially would set 0, then if the plnkr refreshes it goes to the `else` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional `|| undefined` has no effect. You can just use the non-strict comparison with `null` in your `if`.

There is no need to `JSON.parse`, since your retrieved value will be a string representation of a number.

You need to convert the value you read to number, which you can do with unary `+`:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("localValue");
if (value == null) {
    value = 0;
    localStorage.setItem("localValue", 0);
    console.log("newly set variable!");
} else {
    value = +value; // convert to number
    console.log("there was one here before!", value);
}
```

When you modify `value`, maybe via user input, then execute:

```
localStorage.setItem("localValue", value);
```

Although you pass a number, it will be stored as string.

Concerning your `gainValue` function:

```
function gainValue() { 
    value = value + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem("localValue",value));
}
```

The `JSON.parse` is again without effect: you don't use the result, nor do you need it. The `value +` expression will only work correctly if you had converted `value` to a number, like described above, other wise this `+` will function as a string concatenator.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to

```
if (!!localStorage.getItem("localValue") ) {
    var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localValue"));
    console.log("there was one here before!");
}
else
{
  var preValue = 0;
  localStorage.setItem("localValue",preValue);
  var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localValue"));
  console.log("newly set variable!");
}
```

It will check the the value is neither null nor undefined and false